# Prove that the following function is positive

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics

Consider the following function:

$$K(x, y; t) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{e^{-(2n+1)t}}{\sqrt{\pi} 2^n n!} H_n(x) H_n(y) \exp\left(-\frac{(x^2 + y^2)}{2}\right)
$$

This is Mehler's kernel, and can be shown to be positive. $H_n(x)$ refers to the probabilists' nth [Hermite polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials). The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel) on Mehler's kernel has its closed form expression.

However, what about $$K(x, y; t) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{e^{-(2n+1)^2t}}{\sqrt{\pi} 2^n n!} H_n(x) H_n(y) \exp\left(-\frac{(x^2 + y^2)}{2}\right)$$

Is this function also positive? Note that the only change is that the $(2n+1)$ has now been squared.

On running numerical simulations, it seems that this function is positive, and in fact converges to a positive function faster than the previous function. However, how would one go about proving this?

EDIT: I am no longer confident that this function is positive. On running some more simulations, it seems that the function does get very slightly negative close to the origin. However, the values that it takes at those points are of the order of $10^{-8}$. Hence, I am not sure if those are just computational errors on Mathematica's part. This does not seem to happen for the original Mehler's kernel though.

Comment: Maybe, similar to the Mehler kernel, you can show that it is the solution of some positivity preserving PDE with positive initial condition?

Comment: @NateEldredge- Could you explain more about this proof? The proof on Wikipedia seems to be quite different.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, $H_n(x)=\mathbb{E} (x+i\xi)^n$ for a standard Gaussian $\xi$. Thus, your sum is an expectation of $f((x+i\xi)(y+i\eta))$ for independent Gaussian $\xi,\eta$ and $f(s)=\sum_n \frac{e^{-(2n+1)^2t}}{\sqrt{\pi} 2^n n!}s^n$. So possibly some properties of the distribution of $(x+i\xi)(y+i\eta)$ and function $f$ may help

Comment: Each summand of $K$ is the kernel of an orthonormal projection times a positive constant and therefore  positive semidefinite . Therefore K is positive semidefinite.

Comment: @jjcale- It does not seem to be positive semi-definite as per numerical simulations. This is further explained in the "EDIT" section.

Comment: @matilda - The operator associated to K ist positive semidefinite but K is not pointwise positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a proof, but a numerical counterexample:

A high precision analysis with Mathematica reveals that your kernel $K(x,y;t)$ is not positive for all $x,y,t$. One possible counterexample is $x=5$, $y=0$, $t=10^{-2}$, where
$$
K(x,y;t) = -1.80723142573869232733764753939 \, 10^{-7}\,.
$$
A graphical representation of $K(x,y;10^{-2})$ is shown below, negative areas are dark blue.
Due to the exponential convergence, at $t= 10^{-2}$ around 40 terms are sufficient for ca. 50 digits precision.

An explanation for the negative sums: Replace $e^{-t}\mapsto q$ as done on the linked Wikipedia page, and interpret both sums in powers of $q$.
For certain values of $x,y,t$, this very sparse oscillating Taylor series in $q$ seems to lock in at negative values of the partial sum, an effect that does not happen in the full Mehler sum. Note the similarity of the OPs sum with the elliptic theta function $\theta_2(q)$, which is also a sum over $q^{(n-1/2)^2}$. Maybe there is a deeper relation.

Code (note the usage of the probabilistic variant He[] of HermiteH[]):

```
He[n_,x_] = 2^(-n/2) HermiteH[n, x/Sqrt[2]];
K2e[x_,y_,t_,max_] := E^(-(x^2+y^2)/2)/Sqrt[Pi] *
   Sum[(E^(-(2n+1)^2 t) He[n,x] He[n,y])/(2^n n!), {n,0,max}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fred! Something that is surprising to me is the extremely small negative values that the function takes. Also, thank you for the reference to the elliptic theta function, that sounds very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general explaination why such sums cannot be always positive. Consider a self-adjoint second order operator $L$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_n \geq 0$ and eigenfunctions $\phi_n$ (in your case $L=-D^2+x^2$).  The associate heat kernel, that is the integral kernel of $e^{-tL}$ is $K(t,x,y)=\sum_n e^{-\lambda_n t} \phi_n(x)\phi_n(y)$ and is positive under general assumptions.
Your sum is of the form $\tilde K(t,x,y)=\sum_n e^{-\lambda^2_n t} \phi_n(x)\phi_n(y)$ and this is the integral kernel of $e^{-t L^2}$ which cannot be positive since $L^2$ is a fourth-order operator.

Comment: Would you give more details on the last point, why the integral kernel of a fourth-order operator can’t be positive?

Comment: @PietroMajer Maybe the following is not the easiets way....assume that $L$ is self adjoint associated to a form defined in $H^1$ (it is not literally the case of the example). Then $L^2$ has form domain $H^2$. A necessary condition for such a semigroup (that generated by $L^2$ to be positive, is that $u^+$ is in the form domain whenever $u$ is, and this is false for $H^2$ (this criterion is in the book of Ouhabaz, Analysis of heat equation on domains). Similar characterizations hold also in spaces of continuous functions. I can be more precise if you wish.

Comment: @PietroMajer In spaces of continuous functions, if $f \geq 0$, $f(x_0)=0$ and $e^{tA}f \geq 0$ (for small $t$), then $Af(x_0)=\lim t^{-1}(e^{tA}f(x_0)-f(x_0)) \geq 0$ and this property can be true only for first or second order operators. However positivity for large $t$ is possible.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune- You are absolutely correct. I am studying the square of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup generator. Are you aware of any literature or results on it?

Comment: No, I am sorry.